# UITableView crashes array problem help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

i have an UITableView and im trying to return the number of rows using [arrayName count] however when i run the application it seems to be crashing with no errors showing in console. Here is some code .. (also when i test the array in ViewDidLoad using NSLog, it does return '16' so im not sure why it crashes when i do the row count. Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a"];
```

I guess the `- search` method returns an autoreleased object, so that your `elements` object receives the release message after the method `viewDidLoad` returns and hence gets deallocated.

You can fix this in two ways:

- add a `retain` call, like this

  `elements  = [[xpathParser search:@"//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a"] retain];`
- use properties, like this

  `self.elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a"];`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release htmldata as it is already autoreleased. Remove the `[htmldata release];` line and it should work.

Also, you don't, ever, release an object after the `[super dealloc]` line. Bring the line `[elements release];` before the super dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do a retain on elements, and when you assign it, you assign it directly to the property, and don't go through the setter.

Try:

```
self.elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a"];
```

Also, don't forget to release it in the dealloc method.